# iPhone : Font is not affecting to UI

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uifont

I'm using **Constantia** font family in my app, `regular` **bold** and *italic* style is my requirement, the problem I am facing is, I can only get output of regular style, and not the bold and italic, I've already added all three styled fonts into app, and in plist file under `Fonts provided by application` section. I tried with following

```
UIFont *bFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Constantia-Bold" size:24.0];
UIFont *bFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ConstantiaBold" size:24.0];
UIFont *bFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Constantia_Bold" size:24.0];

UIFont *iFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Constantia-Italic" size:24.0];
UIFont *iFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ConstantiaItalic" size:24.0];
UIFont *iFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Constantia_Italic" size:24.0];
```

but not a single case is working, only `UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Constantia" size:24.0];` is working. I know that I'm missing something in font name only.

I tried find font into Mac font's option, I got this font under `All Fonts` section  (left top), one strange this I found is, all `Constantia` **bold**, *italic* and `regular` are installed as a single name, i.e. `Constantia` only.

P.S. Fonts can be downloaded from [here](http://www.fontsner.com/search?s=Constantia).

Comment: UIFont *bFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Constantia Bold" size:24.0];

Comment: Yes, I tried with this too! It was not worked! Is that working at your side?

Comment: Did you install that font ?

Comment: Yes I do installed and know how to add and use custom fonts within app but only problem is with this font.

Comment: May i know that which version you had installed ?

Comment: Mac OSx v.10.7.8 and I'm using iOS 6.0 in XCode 4.5

Comment: Go through this link http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=2054

Answer (score 3):

This is Step for, How to add custom font in Application.

1 - Add `.TTF` font in your application
2 - Modify the `application-info.plist file`.
3 - Add the key **"Fonts provided by application"** to a new row
4 - and add each `.TTF` file (of font) to each line.

For more info read [This](http://www.developers-life.com/how-to-include-ttf-fonts-to-ios-app.html) and [This](http://www.waterworld.com.hk/en/node/157) site.

**For Bold**

```
// Equivalent to [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName-BoldMT" size:17]
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithFamilyName:@"FontName" traits:GSBoldFontMask size:17];
```

**And bold/italic**

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithMarkupDescription:@"font-family: FontName; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold/italic;"]; // set here, either bold/italic.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! As I've mentioned in my question, I am aware of how to add custom fonts into app, and I also able to use `Contantia` `regular` font, but only problem with **Bold** and *Italic* styles. I've edited my question with fonts source url If you'll get time look with that.

Comment: `GSBoldFontMask` type and `fontWithMarkupDescription` method are `UIFont` class method?

Comment: i found it from google for u But i am not sure it work or not ..just try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can see the *real* name of every font available for use by your app:

```
// Log fonts
for (NSString *family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"Font family %@:", family);
    for (NSString *font in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family])
        NSLog("    %@", font);
}
```

Comment: Cyrolle, Oh that's great! I tried it and it logs, 
2013-03-11 16:37:17.788 TestApp[2988:11303] Font family Constantia:
2013-03-11 16:37:17.789 TestApp[2988:11303] Constantia

Comment: This means, it doesn't have **bold** and *italic* fonts available or support?

Comment: Maybe this is a special kind of font that only register one name, and you ask for variants of it depending on the traits you want, as per iPatel's answer. Try to open the different `.ttf`s in FontLab or FontForge to see if they have really unique names.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 16 June 2018: application can be rejected, try find another solution**

```
 #import <dlfcn.h>

// includer for font
NSUInteger loadFonts( )
{
    NSUInteger newFontCount = 0;
    NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.GraphicsServices"];
    const char *frameworkPath = [[frameworkBundle executablePath] UTF8String];

    if (frameworkPath) 
    {
        void *graphicsServices = dlopen(frameworkPath, RTLD_NOLOAD | RTLD_LAZY);

        if (graphicsServices)
        {
            BOOL (*GSFontAddFromFile)(const char *) = dlsym(graphicsServices, "GSFontAddFromFile");

            if (GSFontAddFromFile)
            {

                BOOL verizon = NO;

                NSLog(@"%@",[[UIDevice currentDevice] machine]);

                if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] machine] rangeOfString:@"iPhone3,3"].location != NSNotFound) {
                    verizon = YES;
                }

                for (NSString *fontFile in [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"ttf" inDirectory:nil])
                {
                    if ([fontFile rangeOfString:@"_"].location != NSNotFound && verizon) {
                        newFontCount += GSFontAddFromFile([fontFile UTF8String]);
                    }

                    if ([fontFile rangeOfString:@"-"].location != NSNotFound && !verizon) {
                        newFontCount += GSFontAddFromFile([fontFile UTF8String]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return newFontCount;
}
```

I'm using the function usually :[image])

Comment: I can't understand how this will work as it returns `NSInteger`, how do I make it work! Do you have any reference of this?

Comment: My app got rejected by Apple stating  
"Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework (_GSFontAddFromFile), PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework ()"

I am using the same code as you mentioned. Can you please tell if this method is the reason for app rejection?
Thanks

Comment: @ChiragBhutani probably yes. it was a while ago. So, I don't recommend to use it anymore. Try solution below.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think such type of font is exist in IOS. Please check from here `http://iosfonts.com/`

Comment: That doesn't prevent anyone from adding custom fonts to any project, since iOS 4.x IIRC.

Comment: Yes you are right...but this ans is not protecting any one to using custom fonts, means that if these font style is not supported by IOS ,then you need to use your custom font.